FSA B3155 bottom bracket compatible replacement
I have Orbea orca m35i with Shimano cranks (24mm).
During bottom bracket bearings replacement, the cup got damaged.

It says "FSA B3155" on the cup, FSA support said this would be a compatible replacement:
https://www.bike-components.de/en/FSA/BB86-Press-Fit-41-x-86-5-mm-Bottom-Bracket-for-24-mm-NBD-Cranks-p42632/
But:

Brown is not a good match with a full black bike.
I'm not a huge fan of FSA, so, I'd like to consider other brands
I want to re-check that the support person is not wrong.

What would be the parameters to look for?
Thanks.

Did the photo get changed? This photo has BB386 printed on the cup. Bb386 is not PF86, the Shimano standard which I thought most Orbeas use.

It's the same photo and I don't see BB386 on it. And neither did the FSA support person. My theory is that B3155 is some OEM stuff Orbea bought in bulk and it's not present in the catalogs anywhere.

Ok, looks like I didn’t see what I thought I did.

Well, I bought the one FSA suggested - it was too small.
Maybe I used the wrong words to describe the problem both to the FSA support and here, I'm not sure. By "the cup got damaged" I meant the shell itself. At this point, I'm not even sure if it's the shell or just a part of the BB that didn't suppose to be disassembled anyway. Sorry for the confusion, I spent a week looking at different pressfit specs...
After all, I needed BB386. Went for Token TF38624, hopefully won't have to mess with pressing ever again.

Orbea's site does not say it as clearly as I'd like, but you are looking for a PF86 bottom bracket. Confusingly, the page for your bike says, emphasis mine:

Frameset specs: Orbea Orca carbon OMR 2024, monocoque construction, HS 1,5", BB 386mm, ...

Orbea's FAQ for the Orca models says, emphasis mine:

Can I have a BB30 bottom bracket system?
Our standard bottom bracket is the Shimano Press-Fit, which is incompatible with the BB30 system. However, it is compatible with some 30mm spindle cranksets using special cups.

BB 386 is a standard. It is not what Orbea uses. The Shimano standard is the PF86 standard. You are looking for a PF86 BB for a 24mm spindle. This is the type of BB that the FSA support person suggested.
Make sure you specify a 24mm spindle when searching. PF86 BBs for 30mm crank spindles may exist, but the bearings are smaller and my understanding is that they may be prone to early wear. PF86 BBs for DUB (28.99mm) spindles also exist, but I think they have the same problem. If you get a Shimano BB, it will automatically be for 24mm spindles; Shimano designed the standard, and they've always used 24mm steel spindles and they never considered the 30mm aluminum spindle to be necessary.
Orbea is based in the Basque Country in Spain. Possibly this could account for why they didn't clearly state the BB type in their English documentation. But they're a mid-size global brand, and this isn't an excuse. Manufacturers should clearly and unambiguously state all specifications.
